# How do I iterate over an async function without completely skipping over all the steps in the function?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

[Here is the link to my repo's github page, so you can properly see what I mean.](https://cwitmer34.github.io/milestone-one/categories/animals/animals.html)

I am currently having an issue with my `triviaGame` function when trying to make it recursive, but it's sort of "backfiring" on me in a sense.

You'll notice after you answer the first question, everything seems fine. It goes to the next question fine. After that though, it seems like the iterations of it double? The next answer it skips 2. After that, 4. And finally the remaining 2 (adding up to 10, due to how I am iterating over them).

How might I be able to correctly iterate over a recursive function, so it correctly calls all 10 times, and then returns when it is done?

Been struggling with this for hours, and just can't seem to get it to work. My javascript code is below, sorry for any headaches that it may give you. I know I make some questionable programming decisions. Ignore some of the commented out stuff, it's not finished code yet. I'm a beginner, and hope that once I learn what's going on here it will stick with me, and I don't make a stupid mistake like this again.

```
const _URL = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=27&type=multiple";
const _questionHTML = document.getElementById("question");
const _answerOne = document.getElementById("answer-1");
const _answerTwo = document.getElementById("answer-2");
const _answerThree = document.getElementById("answer-3");
const _answerFour = document.getElementById("answer-4");
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("button[id^=answer-]");
var runCount = 1;
var correct = 0;
// Credits to my friend Jonah for teaching me how to cache data that I get from an API call.
var triviaData = null;

async function getTrivia() {
  return fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=27&type=multiple")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      triviaData = res;
      return res;
    });
}
// anywhere I want the trivia data:
// const trivia = await getTrivia() --- makes the call, or uses the cached data

const shuffleArray = (array) => {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    const temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
};
async function triviaGame() {
  const trivia = await getTrivia();
  async function appendData() {
    let totalAnswers = [
      ...trivia.results[0].incorrect_answers,
      trivia.results[0].correct_answer,
    ];
    // Apparently I need 2 different arrays to sort them because array variables are stored by reference? Learn something new everyday I guess.
    let totalAnswers2 = [...totalAnswers];
    let sorted = shuffleArray(totalAnswers2);
    // Ensures the proper symbol shows instead of the HTML entities
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
      trivia.results[0].question,
      "text/html"
    );
    _questionHTML.textContent = doc.documentElement.textContent;
    console.log(trivia.results[0].correct_answer, "- Correct Answer");
    // Appends info to the DOM
    _answerOne.textContent = sorted[0];
    _answerTwo.textContent = sorted[1];
    _answerThree.textContent = sorted[2];
    _answerFour.textContent = sorted[3];
  }
  async function checkAnswer() {
    btns.forEach((btn) => {
      btn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        console.log(runCount);
        if (event.target.textContent === trivia.results[0].correct_answer) {
          event.target.style.backgroundColor = "#52D452";
          // Disables all buttons after one has been clicked.
          btns.forEach((btn) => {
            btn.disabled = true;
          });
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (runCount === 10) {
              return;
            }
            runCount++;
            correct++;
            btns.forEach((btn) => {
              btn.disabled = false;
            });
            btn.style.backgroundColor = "";
            document.getElementById(
              "amount-correct"
            ).textContent = `${correct}/10`;
            triviaGame();
          }, 2000);
        } else {
          event.target.style.backgroundColor = "#FF3D33";
          btns.forEach((btn) => {
            btn.disabled = true;
          });
          // document.getElementById("correct-text").textContent =
          //   trivia.results[0].correct_answer;
          // document.getElementById("correct-answer").style.visibility =
          //   "visible";
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (runCount === 10) {
              return;
            }
            // document.getElementById("correct-answer").style.visibility =
            //   "hidden";
            btns.forEach((btn) => {
              btn.disabled = false;
              btn.style.backgroundColor = "";
            });
            runCount++;
            triviaGame();
          }, 3500);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  checkAnswer();
  appendData();
}

triviaGame();
```

Any/All responses are much appreciated and repsected. I could use any help y'all are willing to give me. The past 6 hours have been a living hell for me lol.

Answer (score 0):

It's skipping questions once an answer is clicked because every time a button is clicked, **another** event listener is added to the button, **while the original one is active**:

1. On initial load: `triviaGame()` runs which makes `checkAnswer()` run which adds event listeners to each of the buttons.
   Event listeners on buttons: 1.
2. Answer button is clicked, `triviaGame()` runs which makes `checkAnswer()` run which adds event listeners to each of the buttons.
   Event listeners on buttons: 2.
3. Answer button is clicked, `triviaGame()` runs twice (from the 2 listeners attached) which makes `checkAnswer()` run twice where both invocations adds event listeners to each of the buttons.
   Event listeners on buttons: 4.
4. etc.

To fix this, I moved the content of `checkAnswer()` outside of any functions so  it only ever runs once. However, doing this, it loses reference to the upper scope variable `trivia`. To resolve this, I used the `triviaData` variable instead which `checkAnswer()` would have access to and I change references in `appendData()` to match this. Now, `triviaGame()` function only exists to call `appendData()` function inside it; there is little point in this so I merge the two functions together into one function, instead of two nested inside each other.

```js
const _URL = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=27&type=multiple";
const _questionHTML = document.getElementById("question");
const _answerOne = document.getElementById("answer-1");
const _answerTwo = document.getElementById("answer-2");
const _answerThree = document.getElementById("answer-3");
const _answerFour = document.getElementById("answer-4");
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("button[id^=answer-]");
var runCount = 1;
var correct = 0;
// Credits to my friend Jonah for teaching me how to cache data that I get from an API call.
var triviaData = null;

async function getTrivia() {
  return fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=27&type=multiple")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      triviaData = res;
      return res;
    });
}
// anywhere I want the trivia data:
// const trivia = await getTrivia() --- makes the call, or uses the cached data

const shuffleArray = (array) => {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    const temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
};
async function appendData() {
  triviaData = await getTrivia();
  let totalAnswers = [
    ...triviaData.results[0].incorrect_answers,
    triviaData.results[0].correct_answer,
  ];
  // Apparently I need 2 different arrays to sort them because array variables are stored by reference? Learn something new everyday I guess.
  let totalAnswers2 = [...totalAnswers];
  let sorted = shuffleArray(totalAnswers2);
  // Ensures the proper symbol shows instead of the HTML entities
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
    triviaData.results[0].question,
    "text/html"
  );
  _questionHTML.textContent = doc.documentElement.textContent;
  console.log(triviaData.results[0].correct_answer, "- Correct Answer");
  // Appends info to the DOM
  _answerOne.textContent = sorted[0];
  _answerTwo.textContent = sorted[1];
  _answerThree.textContent = sorted[2];
  _answerFour.textContent = sorted[3];
}


    btns.forEach((btn) => {
      btn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        console.log(runCount);
        if (event.target.textContent === triviaData.results[0].correct_answer) {
          event.target.style.backgroundColor = "#52D452";
          // Disables all buttons after one has been clicked.
          btns.forEach((btn) => {
            btn.disabled = true;
          });
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (runCount === 10) {
              return;
            }
            runCount++;
            correct++;
            btns.forEach((btn) => {
              btn.disabled = false;
            });
            btn.style.backgroundColor = "";
            document.getElementById(
              "amount-correct"
            ).textContent = `${correct}/10`;
            appendData();
          }, 2000);
        } else {
          event.target.style.backgroundColor = "#FF3D33";
          btns.forEach((btn) => {
            btn.disabled = true;
          });
          // document.getElementById("correct-text").textContent =
          //   trivia.results[0].correct_answer;
          // document.getElementById("correct-answer").style.visibility =
          //   "visible";
          setTimeout(() => {
            if (runCount === 10) {
              return;
            }
            // document.getElementById("correct-answer").style.visibility =
            //   "hidden";
            btns.forEach((btn) => {
              btn.disabled = false;
              btn.style.backgroundColor = "";
            });
            runCount++;
  appendData();
          }, 3500);
        }
      });
    });

appendData();
```

```html
<div id="amount-correct"></div>
<h1 id="question"></h1>
<button id="answer-1"></button>
<button id="answer-2"></button>
<button id="answer-3"></button>
<button id="answer-4"></button>
```